# Multiple EmbeddableDocumentStore in 1 Application

Tags: ravendb

i want to use 2 different EmbeddableDocumentStores in my application.
i used the logic suggested [here](https://ayende.com/blog/160161/managing-ravendb-document-store-startup).

When i open the second store, i get this error: "Temp path already used by another database instance."

as i understand, i could overcome this by specifying a DataDirectory for every database.
Doing that i get the above error when i start the first query after initializing the first instance.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a single connection string, you are trying to open both document stores on the same path.
Use different path for each

Comment: I'm doing that already. If i specify a DataDirectory for the Store, like this: 
DataDirectory = $"~\\Databases\\{databaseName}" then i see that the database is created, but at the end of a BulkInsert Operation, i get a Syste.AggregateException with an Inner Exception exactly as above.

When i leave the "DataDirectory" off, i can see my database being created and i also have a database named "System" created.

In this case, i don't get the error on the BulkInsert.

But as soon as i open the second Store, i'll have the error.
Which seems to be ok, because i didn't specify a Data folder

Comment: Ah, i see now. With an EmbeddableStore i am not working with databases. Each embedded docstore is it's own database and i use the DataDirectory to create the store. Right?